# Very high standard error in glm (R)

Tags: r, regression, logistic

In an effort to understand AIC more intuitively, I created a synthetic dataset with the following:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df['Y'] <- (runif(1000,0,2) + df$X4 + df$X5) < 2
```

When I run `summary(glm(Y~., data=df, family = 'binomial'(link='logit')))` I get this output:

```
Call:
glm(formula = Y ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.26754  -1.05215  -0.00007   0.00009   1.32843  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  19.476407 481.689046   0.040    0.968
X1            0.115944   0.180479   0.642    0.521
X2           -0.016184   0.180372  -0.090    0.929
X3            0.027578   0.179069   0.154    0.878
X4          -19.614964 481.688977  -0.041    0.968
X5          -19.539739 481.688977  -0.041    0.968
X6            0.155426   0.179888   0.864    0.388
X7           -0.089721   0.179614  -0.500    0.617
X8           -0.002851   0.179913  -0.016    0.987
X9           -0.010019   0.179219  -0.056    0.955
X10          -0.090924   0.180055  -0.505    0.614

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1386.29  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  694.98  on 989  degrees of freedom
AIC: 716.98

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

Shouldn't X4 and X5 have tiny standard errors and tiny p-values? What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't explained your model and what it's intended to do, but you can at least analyze the data you generated.  You might be surprised to see what's going on.  Examine the relationships among `X4`, `X5` and `Y`. Since your example is not reproducible, you might get different results than others, so look at several simulations.  Use `with(df,table(X4,X5,Y))`.

Comment: And, search this site for the Hauck-Donner effect